# Exporting pg_backups to S3 using Heroku (Django)

Tags: postgresql, heroku

How can I export pgbackups dump (database backup) to `s3` bucket.

Some of the `pgbackup export/restore` commands are as follows.

```
$ heroku pgbackups:capture
$ curl -o latest.dump `heroku pgbackups:url`
```

To restore database from s3 we can do something like this.

```
heroku pgbackups:restore DATABASE 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/me/items/3H0q/mydb.dump'
```

How can we export it from Heroku command line or from python script?

Answer (score 0):

Just configuring the heroku [db backup s3](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/devsenexx/heroku-db-backup-s3) buildpack. I know it is late but maybe for future insterested.